# When using asp.net websrevices (.asmx) is there away to require specific permission to access a specific method?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, asmx

Can I set a hardcoded permission id as a method attribute for example:

```
[WebMethod]
["PermissionId=8"]
function myWebMethod(){

}
```

and then have the client credentials that I will later on map to a user and check hos permissions?
I want to avoid adding token or credentials to each method